# "Meatless Alternatives" at grocery confusing/unclear?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

There is a freezer section at my local grocery labeled "Meatless Alternatives" (pictured below). Strictly construing this means this section should contain alternatives to meatless foods, i.e., meat. This section stocks veggie burgers and vegan choices.

Shouldn't the section sign more accurately read "Meatless", "Meatless Options", or "Meat Alternatives?"

[image]

Comment: Compounds are funny: `meat alternatives`- alternatives _of_ meat (like sunrise, rise of sun); `meatless alternatives`- alternatives _that are_ meatless (like blackboard, board that is black). Both make sense if you know the context. They probably went with `meatless` because it's _less_ confusing to vegetarians, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

It's meatless alternatives, i.e. alternatives to meat food and they don't contain any meat. I think this is quite correct phrase.

Comment: If the meaning is "alternatives to meat" then the sign should read "meat alternatives." The current sign is practically a double negative.